# Map selected radio button to existing post category: Cannot assign "'Artikel'": "Post.category" must be a "Category" instance

Tags: python, html, django

I want to map radio buttons to given categories. One way is to do this with the help of a choice field. I don't know if this is a good approach.

I have seen many other articles and SO-posts but they did not point me to a direction from where I could see my mistake - so after many hours of research I wanted to ask you here. Thanks!

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Kategorie")
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ....
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Kategorie",
```

forms.py

```
CAT_CHOICES= [
    ('Artikel', 'Artikel'),
    ('Videos', 'Videos'),
    ('Anderes', 'Anderes'),
    ]

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CAT_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = Post # is this throwing an error because I only handle the 'Post' model?
        fields = [
            'title',
             ...
            'category',
        ]
```

views.py

```
def function_name(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # error happens here
```

template.html:

```
<label>Artikel</label>
<input id="category0" type="radio" name="category" value="Artikel">
<label>Videos</label>
<input id="category1" type="radio" name="category" value="Videos">
<label>Anderes</label>
<input id="category2" type="radio" name="category" value="Anderes">
```

output:

```
ValueError at /

Cannot assign "'Artikel'": "Post.category" must be a "Category" instance.
```

[image: error message]

What would be a good practice to handle this?

I am thankful for any advice.

---

### SOLUTION

Even if I have spent a lot of time looking for my mistake I could not find it. With the two first answers I got pointed to the right direction. I have adjusted my template file and the form:

```
CAT_CHOICES= [
    (1, 'Artikel'),
    (2, 'Videos'),
    (3, 'Anderes'),
    ]

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
             ...
            'category',
        ]
```

and

```
<label>Artikel</label>
<input id="category0" type="radio" name="category" value="1">
<label>Videos</label>
<input id="category1" type="radio" name="category" value="2">
<label>Anderes</label>
<input id="category2" type="radio" name="category" value="3">
```

Where the value is according to the id of the category.
It would be interesting to know how to link the actual title and not the id.

Thank you!

---

### UPDATE 2

As pointed by Matt the additional choices variable is not necessary. Thanks a lot it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to reference your `Category` instances by their `id` values. That would mean changing the choices in your **forms.py** to something like:

```py
CAT_CHOICES= [
    (1, 'Artikel'),
    (2, 'Videos'),
    (3, 'Anderes'),
]
```

If you have hard-coded those options in your template, they would need to be changes to something like:

```html
<label>Artikel</label>
<input id="category0" type="radio" name="category" value="1">
<label>Videos</label>
<input id="category1" type="radio" name="category" value="2">
<label>Anderes</label>
<input id="category2" type="radio" name="category" value="3">
```

**UPDATE**

The `CAT_CHOICES` are only required if you need to limit which options are displayed or validated.

You also don't need to redefine `ModelChoiceField`, as this is the [default form field for a ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types). This should work:

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
             ...
            'category',
        ]
```

If you don't want to hard-code the options in your template, you can allow the form to display all Categories as options. You will need to specify the `RadioSelect` widget in your form:

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
             ...
            'category',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'category': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

Then in your template, replace what you have posted with the `{{ form.category }}` tag (assuming `form` is the context variable name you are using). More info about how to control display of a `RadioSelect` widget can be found in the [widget docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect).

Comment: Thank you very much. The correct solution is actually in the middle of both answers from you and roxolid: from your answer I took the choices and the value. I will post my final solution to my question. Which answer should I mark as correct now?

Comment: @buchstabe No problem. I've updated my answer with some extra information. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve this properly with a ModelForm.

Use as normal Form instead like:

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

I haven't tested this with your code, but that's how I would go about it.

Comment: Thank you very much. The correct solution is actually in the middle of both answers from you and Matt: from your answer I took the `category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())` but I let the form a `ModelForm`. I will post my final solution to my question.